# How to debug reactjs when browser loads ok but phone does not

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I'm wondering if there are some tips on how to track down the cause for my react.js app not loading.

- In Chrome OK
- Physical iPhone 6 - OK
- In iPhone Simulator 6s - Not OK
- Old iPad2 - Not OK

I've `npm install -g react-devtools` and added `<script src="http://192.168.0.21:8097"></script>` to my index.html.

The script seems to be loading but I only see `Waiting for roots to load...`

I've broken my build over the last few commits and as a last resort I can check all the changes for the cause. But, I prefer to see what the "real error" is.

Any suggestions or tips on how to debug?

Comment: Are you using react-intl per chance?

Comment: Yes, I have the react-intl provider. Are there some catches?

Comment: Older versions of Safari (most likely like the one on your iPad 2) require the Intl.js polyfill to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to a mac, you can plug the device in and from the Safari developer menu, access the console from your device's safari.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html for a complete step-by-step.

Comment: Great! I could get the error. Thanks! `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.` Now to find the fix...